# Retrieve secrets from Key Vault to a .Net Core app running in AKS, is CSI Driver necessary?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-aks, azure-keyvault

I am currently working moving from using App Services to Azure Kubernetes Service for a group of APIs running in .Net Core. It is all going well with the exception of Azure Key Vault, so I am hoping that somebody can help me out.

I need to store database connection strings for each of these APIS securely, so have chosen to use Azure Key Vault, but I am not actually sure why or if the [Secrets Store CSI driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver) is necessary for what we are aiming for. Can we not just create an access policy in Azure Key Vault for the AKS node to have access too to retrieve the key? Or just use a managed identity? I can then use the Key Vault SDK in the app code.

If anyone can shed some light on this I would really appriciate it as I just seem to be coming across the CSI driver in all documentation/videos I find. If we do need to use it, I would just like to know why so I have a better understanding.

I have tried using the CSI driver, as well as trying to retrieve without the CSI driver. At the moment I am struggling to get either to work. However once I know if I need the CSI driver, I can go with the correct approach, as currently I am bouncing around between different ones.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options (injecting secrets using the Secrets Store CSI Driver or fetching them directly from the vault in the application using .NET SDK) are perfectly valid options.

The secrets store CSI driver acts as an intermediate layer between the application and the key vault and makes the secrets from the vault available to the application as either files or environment variables. The secret store driver uses a managed identity attached to the underlying scaleset to access the key vault.
This means that:

- The application becomes independent of how the keys are stored at rest, which makes it easier to test locally as well as deploy in environments other than Azure.
- The application does not need to have access or manage credentials to the key vault since the secrets is *pushed* into the container where the applications runs by the CSI driver (as opposed to being *pulled* in by the application itself)

When using the Azure SDK your application will connect directly to the key vault and there is no need for an intermediate component, but this couples your application tightly to Azure Key vault. You also end up with the challenge of how to provide credentials to your application to authenticate to the key vault. Since those credentials cannot be stored in a key vault,  you need another construct providing you an identity, like [AAD Pod Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-azure-ad-pod-identity) or the newer [Azure AD workload identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-ad-workload-identity/azure-ad-workload-identity/). So even though you don't use the Secret Store CSI driver you will most likely need another component to facilitate authentication to the key vault.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have gone ahead with using Azure AD workload identity, and it is working. I dont think there is a need for us to use the CSI driver.

Comment: "The application does not need to have access or manage credentials to the key vault since the"... Where's the rest of the sentence?

Comment: @user692942: ... "since the secrets is *pushed* into the container where the applications runs by the CSI driver (as opposed to being *pulled* in by the application itself)"
Thanks for pointing the missing part out. I have updated my answer.